# Why do OpenGL 4 GL_RGBA2 and GL_RGBA4 sized format have a base format of GL_RGB instead of GL_RGBA?

Tags: opengl, opengl-es

According to the [OpenGL 4 documentation](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glTexImage2D.xhtml), GL_RGBA2 and GL_RGBA4 have a base format of GL_RGB even though they have alpha bits.

This is inconsistent with the [OpenGL 3 ES documentation](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL-Refpages/es3.0/html/glTexImage2D.xhtml). Is this due to some sort of legacy issue?

Comment: They don't; That documentation has a typo. The authoritative source is the [OpenGL spec](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.core.pdf), where in table 8.12 RGBA2 and RGBA4 clearly listed as having RGBA base internal format.

Comment: Can you post this as an answer please? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this question has no official answer after a week, I'll post on Yakov Galka's behalf.

"They don't; That documentation has a typo. The authoritative source is the [OpenGL spec](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.core.pdf), where in table 8.12 RGBA2 and RGBA4 clearly listed as having RGBA base internal format."